# Printing duplicate strings and how many times they appear in a file C++

Tags: c++

Here is the question I have to solve and the code I've written so far.

Write a function named printDuplicates that accepts an input stream and an output stream as parameters.

The input stream represents a file containing a series of lines. Your function should examine each line looking for consecutive occurrences of the same token on the same line and print each duplicated token along how many times it appears consecutively.

Non-repeated tokens are not printed. Repetition across multiple lines (such as if a line ends with a given token and the next line starts with the same token) is not considered in this problem.

**For example, if the input file contains the following text:**

> *hello how how are you you you you*
>
> *I I I am Jack's Jack's smirking smirking smirking smirking smirking revenge*
>
> *bow wow wow yippee yippee yo yippee yippee yay yay yay*
>
> *one fish two fish red fish blue fish*
>
> *It's the Muppet Show, wakka wakka wakka*

**My expected result should be:**

> how*2 you*4
>
> I*3 Jack's*2 smirking*5
>
> wow*2 yippee*2 yippee*2 yay*3
>
> ```
> \n
> ```
>
> wakka*3

**Here is my function:**

```
 1    void printDuplicates(istream& in, ostream& out)
 2    {
 3        string line; // Variable to store lines in
 4        while(getline(in, line)) // While there are lines to get do the following
 5        {
 6            istringstream iss(line); // String stream initialized with line
 7            string word; // Current word
 8            string prevWord; // Previous word
 9            int numWord = 1; // Starting index for # of a specific word
 10            while(iss >> word) // Storing strings in word variable
 11            {
 12                if (word == prevWord) ++numWord; // If a word and the word  13 before it are equal add to word counter
 14                else if (word != prevWord) // Else if the  word and the word before it are not equal
 15                {
 16                    if (numWord > 1) // And there are at leat two copies of that word
 17                    {
 18                        out << prevWord <<  "*" << numWord << " "; // Print out "word*occurrences"
 19                    }
 20                    numWord = 1; // Reset the num counter variable for next word
 21                }
 22                prevWord = word; // Set current word to previous word, loop begins again
 23            }
 24            out << endl; // Prints new line between each iteration of line loop
 25        }
 26    }
```

**My result thus far is:**

> how*2
>
> I*3 Jack's*2 smirking*5
>
> wow*2 yippee*2 yippee*2

I have **tried** adding (**|| iss.eof()**), (**|| iss.peek == EOF**), etc inside the nested else if statement on **Line 14**, but I am unable to figure this guy out. I need some way of knowing I'm at the end of the line so my else if statement will be true and try to print the last word on the line.

Comment: You could just repeat the `if (numWord > 1)` test and output statement after the end of the inner loop.